# Application of 2nd fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus

I would like to clarify the usage of the 2nd fundamental theorem of calculus, in 3 parts.
For all 3 parts, consider $F'(a)$ to be

$$
F'(a) = \frac{1}{1+a+a^2}
$$

The questions are:

1. Find $ \frac{d}{dy}\int^y_1 F'(a) \,da $
2. Find $\frac{d}{dy}\int^1_y F'(a) \,da$
3. Find $\frac{d}{dy}\int^{y^2}_1 F'(a)\, da$

My working for each of the questions are:

1.

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dy} \int^y_1 F'(a) \,da  &= \frac{d}{dy}\begin{bmatrix}F(y) - F(1)\end{bmatrix}
\\&=F'(y)
\\&=\frac{1}{1+y+y^2}.
\end{align*}
$$

2.

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dy} \int^1_y F'(a) \,da  &= \frac{d}{dy}\begin{bmatrix}F(1) - F(y)\end{bmatrix}
\\&=-F'(y)
\\&=\frac{-1}{1+y+y^2}.
\end{align*}
$$

3.

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dy} \int^{y^2}_1 F'(a) \,da  &= \frac{d}{dy}\begin{bmatrix}F(y^2) - F(1)\end{bmatrix}
\\&=F'(y^2)
\\&=\frac{2y}{1+y^2+y^4}.
\end{align*}
$$

**UPDATE**:
I shall update (3) with the chain rule working.

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dy} \int^{y^2}_1 F'(a) \,da  &= \frac{d}{dy}\begin{bmatrix}F(y^2) - F(1)\end{bmatrix}
\\&=F'(y^2)(2y)
\\&=\frac{1}{1+(y^2)+(y^2)^2} (2y) \tag{by chain rule}
\\&=\frac{2y}{1+y^2+y^4}.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: The third one would need a chain rule. Though, you do have used it for final answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answers are correct. However, one should note that$\dfrac{dF(y^2)}{dy}=F'(y^2)\cdot2y$(Chain rule). Your final answers are perfectly fine but the intermediate step is wrong.

Comment: I shall make that update into my equation for clarity purposes. I think that forgetting the chain rule will be a common mistake in exams.